# How can I change the amount of promotional emails that go out per batch?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, email, email-templates, email-queue

How can I change the amount of promotional emails that go out per batch? Right now, it's set to 100, but I'm trying to increase it to 200.

Comment: what do you mean by "promotional emails"? newsletters? or something else? Can you explain what and how you are sending?

Comment: Yes, I am currently working on sending newsletter emails, specifically for promotional purposes. The current queue allows for 100 emails to be sent at a time, but I would like to increase this limit to 200.

Comment: Which module are you using to send the newsletter emails via queues? OOTB newsletter doesn't use queues.

Comment: I'm using Mageplaza smtp, and the host is AWS emails